# Convert varchar to bigint and return results only greater than a specific number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Q1. Why doesn't my conversion work in the below trials?

Q2. How to convert varchar to bigint and return results only greater than 90 from a varchar column?

I am on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

I know I can retrieve numbers by simply:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(column1) = 1
```

but now I want to add to it and return results only greater than 90. But before I can do that I keep getting this error when trying to convert. I am trying to convert varchar to bigint because I have some really big numbers in the varchar column. Here is the error  --> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

for example I have these values in the column

```
50
65
98
199
9999999
9999999999
```

Expected results

```
98
199
9999999
9999999999
```

Tried queries

Trial 1

```
SELECT 
    CAST(P0.column1 as bigint) as column1
FROM
     (
      SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(column1) = 1
     ) P0
```

Trial 2

```
select case when isnumeric(column1 ) = 1 
        then cast(column1 as bigint) 
        else NULL 
   end
from table
```

Trial 3

```
select * 
into TempTable 
FROM table WHERE Cast(ISNUMERIC(column1) as bigint) = 1 and column1> '90';
```

Trial 4

```
Insert into TempTable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
select column1, column2, column3, column4, Cast(ISNUMERIC(column5) as 
bigint) 
from table;
```

Trial 5

```
select cast(Param_Value as bigint) from Setting_Alert_Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not execute the `WHERE` clause before other expressions, necessarily.  Subqueries and CTEs -- same lack of guarantee.  SQL Server can rearrange the elements of a query, sometimes causing problems like this.

In addition, `ISNUMERIC()` doesn't guarantee that something can be converted to an integer.

Just use `TRY_CONVERT()` or `TRY_CAST()` instead:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(column1 as bigint) as column1
FROM table
```

Comment: Can you please answer both of my questions? I got an error with this query
      SELECT TRY_CAST(Param_Value as bigint) as Param_Value
             FROM Setting_Alert_Value
             Where Param_Value > 90

Comment: @DheerajDixit . . . You need to use `TRY_CAST()` for all references to the column.

Comment: Sweet! that worked! you da best! here is the query `code` SELECT TRY_CAST(Param_Value as bigint) as Param_Value
FROM Setting_Alert_Value
Where TRY_CAST (Param_Value as bigint) > 90
order by Param_Value; `code`

Comment: @DheerajDixit . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: I unaccepted it because it wasn't exactly the answer to my question but it helped. I posted the exact answer below. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

here is the exact query that worked for me

```
  SELECT TRY_CAST(column1 as bigint) as column1 FROM table Where TRY_CAST (column1 as bigint) > 90 order by column1;
```